# How does the clock() function works internally?

Tags: c, clock, timing, processor, standard-library

What is the mechanism that is used internally by the function clock() in the c standard library and other related timing functions? Can someone write a similar function in C? Or in assembly?

What knowledge is needed to write such functions manually? Is it necessary to know details about the structure of the processor?

Comment: Why would you want to reprogram clock manually?

Comment: @izlin I do not want to reprogram the clock manually.

Answer (score 1):

The actual implementation of clock() depends on the running kernel. Note that in full-blown Operating Systems you are restricted from accessing the hardware directly and have to use the kernel mechanics such as syscalls.

For example by looking at [linux version of clock() in glibc](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/clock.c) you can see that it uses the function __times() defined in [times.c](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/times.c) which in turn uses Linux syscall.

Compare that with [BSD version](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/a2f34833b1042d5d8eeb263b4cf4caaea138c4ad/sysdeps/unix/bsd/clock.c) which is clearly different and relies on __getrusage().

In order to write such functions yourself you have to know the kernel and that usually requires you to know the details of the hardware it runs on.

Comment: but isn't the Linux kernel the same even if it runs on intel or a PowerPC or something else? How is the kernel different on different hardware?

Comment: Depending what you mean by "the same". The interfaces exposed by the Linux kernel minimize the platform-dependency, but it's not exactly the same binary that runs on Intel or a PowerPC (also it uses separate platform dependent source files during compilation). The "running kernel" is not limited to the Linux kernel, it includes BSD, Solaris, etc.

Comment: is it possible that some Linux system call to work on a hardware platform and NOT work on another hardware platform? And what is running kernel?